Create a Seurat Object in Single Cell analysis in R using GEO matrix.txt data
I am new in bioinformatic analysis and single-cell RNA analysis using Seurat in R. I want to analyze the samples GSM7030509,    GSM7030510, GSM7030511, and GSM7030512 from GEO accession GSE224727, but data is in mtx.txt format and I don't know how to create a Seurat Oject.
# Load Data

data11 <- data.table::fread("GSM7030511.matrix.txt.gz", header = F)
data[1:5,1:5]

 data11[1:5,1:5]
                      V1        V2                 V3                 V4                 V5
1:                   GID      Gene CGCGATGGAGGC_Tumor CGACGCTTATTG_Tumor CTGGGTCTCTAC_Tumor
2:             CRERECOMB CRERECOMB                  0                  0                  0
3:  ENSMUSG00000000001.4     Gnai3                  0                  0                  0
4: ENSMUSG00000000003.15      Pbsn                  0                  0                  0
5: ENSMUSG00000000028.14     Cdc45                  0                  0                  0

The first two columns are the Features and the colnames are the Barcodes. The numbers compound the Matrix.
# Create Matrix
matrix1 <- data11[2:48530 , 3:7278]

# Create Features Objects
Features11 <- data11[, 1:2]

The barcodes I already had a saved dataframe, so I've just loaded it
# Create Barcode Objects
bc1 <- read.table('barcodes1.txt', header = F)
Barcd1 <- as.data.frame(t(bc1))

# Create Seurat Obj
rep1 <- ReadMtx(
  mtx = matrix1, 
  features = Features11,
  cells = Barcd1
  )

When I try to create the Seurat Object this occur this error:
Error in path.expand(path) : argumento 'path' inválido


You should not use header = FALSE with fread() when you actually have headers. It will cause the column type to be character instead of numeric.
data11 <- data.table::fread("GSM7030511.matrix.txt.gz")
matrix1 <- as.matrix(data11[,3:ncol(data11)])

Set row names (here I assume you want to use the Gene column):
rownames(matrix1) <- data11$Gene

ReadMtx() is for reading in a file, so it expects a file path as an argument. Since you have already read in the data, create the Seurat object like this:
rep1 <- CreateSeuratObject(matrix1)

